# Why Boolean Modifier can not properly work with meshes a bit more complexed than Cube and Cylinder

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

When I try to cut holes in simple mesh everything is OK
[image]

But When it try same operation with more complex meshes (see below)
[image]

I end up with some messy ununderstandable geometry (which I have no idea how was made), as you can see below.
[image]

In second case both meshes are Non-Manifold, yet geometry are not "Quads only" and somewhat messy - may be the problem is here in geometry with mixed quads, ngons, and triangles? Should I fix geometry first and only then try to apply Bolean?
Thank you

Comment: did you try both, fast and exact? is your face orientation right? pls provide blend file....because "normally" boolean works and the mistake "normally" sits before the screen

Comment: First of all, you are using Blender version from 5 years ago. I would recommend updating to the current one. There are boolean improvements in newer versions. Other than that, you are right - booleans require tidy geometry. You should avoid closely overlapping geometry as well - like faces on the same plane in the same place or vertices from different meshes at the same position. Non-manifold geometry may also be an issue.

Comment: As @MartynasŽiemys says, your Blender version is way too old, there have been improvements on the _Boolean_ modifier. For example, when Chris asks about trying _Fast_ and _Exact_ mode - your modifier shouldn't even have those options. And he asks about face orientation - I can already see that the cylinders in the lower screenshots have inverted faces pointing inwards.